# Using override method from two classes

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist, tostring

I gott two toString() and want to print them both, by calling only one of them.
I must have objects of class1 as Array and class2 as ArrayList.

Main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    Class1 []class1 = new Class1[2];
    ArrayList<Class2> class2List = new ArrayList<Class2>();

    for(int i=0; i<class1.length; i++){
        class1[i] = getClass1Obj();
        class2List.add(getClass2Obj());   
    } 

    for(int i=0; i<class1.length; i++){
        printClass1(class1, i);            
    }                
}

public static void print(Class1[] cls1, int index){
        System.out.println(cls1[index].toString());
}
```

Class1:

```
private Class2 class2;    

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getMethod() + getMethod2() + class2.toString();                             
}
```

Class2:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getMethod3() + getMethod4();
}
```

This doesn't work. May it be because of the way I create the different objects?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: it works when I only print the toString from class1

Comment: What error you get? maybe class2 is null. i don't see where you do setClass2(class2);

Comment: I get a nullpointerexeption.

Comment: It is not possible to diagnose your problem given the code you have posted here. Please add more relevant code, such as the body of `printClass1(s)` and all `getMethod#()` and `getObject#()`.

Comment: nullpointerexeption = class2 is null.

Comment: where should i do setClass2(class2)?

Comment: class2List.add(getClass2Obj()); "getClass2Obj"  is a method that creates and returns a class2-object, isn't this beeing stored in the arraylist?

Comment: Yes, it will add the reference in the ArrayList, but you are reading from class2 field which is null in the class1 instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a reference to class2 when you create class1 instances

```
for(int i=0; i<class1.length; i++){
    class1[i] = getClass1Obj();
    Class2 class2 = getClass2Obj();
    class1[i].setClass2(class2);
    class2List.add(class2);   
}
```

Remember to create a setClass2 method

```
public setClass2(Class2 class2) { this.class2 = class2; }
```

In this way, class1 will have a reference to class2 and can use class2 toString